# Parameter has no default value, SQL Query doesn't work

Tags: variables, delphi-7

```
SELECT *
FROM Candidate
WHERE Candidate.Username = CurrentUser
```

CurrentUser is a global variable (string) which gets the username from the login. When I try to use the SQLQuery with a TDBGrid I get the error, Parameter CurrentUser has no default value.

```
unit UntVar;

interface

Var Currentuser:String;


implementation

end.
```

Code for the Global variable.

`CurrentUser := EdtUser.Text;` Code for when currentuser gains a value.

Comment: This is probably happens, because you not defining `CurrentUser` and trying to give it to the query.

Comment: So I would have to give Currentuser a value before I could use it in the query?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Code:

```
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear();
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Candidate');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE Candidate.UserName = :CurrUser');
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('CurrUser').Value := CurrentUser;

  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to assign the content of the global variable to the parameter. (They're not visible or connected in any way. The SQL.Text is simply a string, and the GlobalUser variable is simply a variable holding a string. You need to do something to provide the value to the SQL itself.)

You need something like this:

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Candidate WHERE Candidate.UserName = :CurrUser';
Query.ParamByName('CurrUser').AsString := CurrentUser;  // Your global var
Query.Open;
```

Comment: As I'm using a TADOQuery I'm unsure where I would put the code or in what format/syntax